# How to organise Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make a website where I start writing books. I want to build a function to add a chapter to a book.

I already made the database and the possibility to create a book. But I don't know how to organise the database. I want to be able to add chapters to a book. How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "organize" - would be great if you could also post an illustration or example of your current DB structure.

Comment: Right now, I'm using 1 table in MySQL for the books. What I want is that I want to be able to add chapters with text to each book(record).

Comment: Ok, You need a relationship table with the books will be chapters as containing primary id of the books table

Comment: well too bad they put it on hold. I guess i know what you meant with your question but without any example of code it sounds way too generic for some people

Comment: You can create a table for chapters which must be referenced to books table.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a table named chapter with columns:

```
id INT 11 PK AI
number INT 11
title VARCHAR(255)
text TEXT
book_id INT 11
```

Book_id will be a foreign key from your book table. This way you can make new chapters for the books you want, the books_id indicates which book it's from, the title well that's obvious, text also obvious and the number would be the chapter number.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a schema like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE Books
    (`id` int, `bookName` varchar(55), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Books
    (`id`, `bookName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'book1', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (2, 'book2', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'book3', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;

CREATE TABLE Chapters
    (`id` int, `bookId` int , `chapterName` varchar(55), `content` text)
;

INSERT INTO Chapters
    (`id`, `bookId`, `chapterName`, `content`)
VALUES
    (1,1, 'chap1', 'blah'),
    (2,1, 'chap2', 'hello'),
    (3,2, 'chap1', 'world')
;
```

Then you can join the tables by doing:

```
SELECT
  c.chapterName , c.content ,b.bookName
FROM
  Chapters c
LEFT JOIN
  Books b
ON
  c.bookId = b.id
```